# How to change camera default save location?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, camera, sony-xperia-s

When I was using the camera of my Sony Xperia S, the following message popped up.

[image: screencap]

So how do you change the default save location of *your camera* (as highlighted with red underline)?

Note: Yes, my memory was full and the message stopped showing up after deleting some files of course. I just want to know how to **change the default for CAMERA**.

Comment: Well, you could try another camera app from the playstore, for sure one of it will let you change its files destination. As far as I know, Default ICS camera does not allow you to change default location. I've been looking around the db settings with sqlite, and I found one interesting you could check out (if you're root) it would be `com.android.providers.media>internal.db>files`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was literally *not* with changing the location but with the capacity of the existing location. I freed-up some space from my SD card memory (which is hard-coded in to the mobile) and the problem went away.

I could not find any of the options provided in the other answers. There is no `gear icon` nor an option called *Storage*

Answer (score -1):

When you see this message first select <kbd>OK</kbd> then select sub menu and it gives you options such as scenes selection, resolution, flash etc. What you got to do is slide the tile and go to the second tile. There you should be able to find data storage where you can change where you want to save your pictures at.

Alternately, the gear icon (for settings) in the slider at the bottom of the camera (where you select flash, effects, etc.) will take you to the settings dialog where you can then choose a different save slot (under Save Location).

Comment: Well, There is no such option in that sub menu. I checked that before I posted my question here.

Answer (score -1):

For ICS, while using the camera, simply click on the gear icon, then slide down to the settings that lie below the top ones: "Storage" is next to last; click on it, and you can set it to "memory card" (changing it from "Phone").

Also, you may want to tweak the "Shutter sound" while down there to "off" to avoid that noisy clicking

Answer (score -1):

In my xperia E1,  when you are in the camera app, i click on the three dots in the top left corner and then on the second tab, top right with the crossed knife and fork.  The saving location is in that list.  There will only be internal and sd card options and usually your sd card is bigger than the internal storage. Might be best if you can get a bigger sd card.

Answer (score -1):

On my Wiko Cink Five, I have to go in the settings, then storage, and select default storage as phone storage or memory card. Changing it to memory card makes the pictures taken with the camera to be saved in the memory card.

Comment: Thanks for the info but OP already made it clear that there was no **Storage** option available in the **Settings**. The answer is http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37417/how-to-change-camera-default-save-location/52445#52445