# Storing pictures on an external storage media

Tags: external-sd, camera, storage, gallery

So, I'm new to Android but I came to the conclusion that on 4.2.2, the Camera app doesn't exist as such and is actually part of the Gallery app package.

Now my problem is [it isn't possible to change the default camera location](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37417/how-to-change-camera-default-save-location) (the option just doesn't exist for some Android versions or devices, that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere) and I can't seem to find a way to move the Gallery app pictures storage location to an SD card for example.

Do I have to switch to a third party camera+gallery app which will allow this option, or is there another solution (other than copying the files via the File System Manager on a regular basis, thus making said photos disappear from the gallery)?